# Using a PHP variable in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6

Before using ECMAScript 6, I used PHP variables in my Javascript via `<?php echo $myVar ?>`.

With ES6 and `<script type="module" src="my ES6 file"></script>`, it seems to work no more (I get a `Unexpected token '<'` error in Chrome.

What could I do instead to use a PHP variable in an ES6 module ?

Here is the code that triggers the problem:

```
import Section from './Section/Section.js'
import ExpressionSearchPanelConsult 
    from './ExpressionSearchPanelConsult/ExpressionSearchPanelConsult.js'
import ExpressionPopularTags 
    from './ExpressionPopularTags/ExpressionPopularTags.js'
import ExpressionPersonalTags 
    from './ExpressionPersonalTags/ExpressionPersonalTags.js'

let expressionSearchSection = new Section(
    document.getElementById("ExpressionSearchSection"),
    document.getElementById("ExpressionSearchSectionContent"),
    document.getElementById("ExpressionSearchSectionArrow")
);

let expressionSearchPanelConsult = new ExpressionSearchPanelConsult(
    document.getElementById("ExpressionSearchPanelConsult")
);

let expressionPopularTags = new ExpressionPopularTags(
    document.getElementById("ExpressionPopularTags"),
    expressionSearchPanelConsult
);

if ('undefined' != document.getElementById("ExpressionPersonalTags"))
{
    let memberId = <?php echo (string)($_SESSION['memberId']); ?>; // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    let expressionPersonalTags = new ExpressionPersonalTags(
        document.getElementById("ExpressionPersonalTags"),
        expressionSearchPanelConsult,
        memberId
    );
}
```

And this Javascript/ES6 code is imported with:

```
<script
    type="module"
    src="<?php echo pathForHtml(__DIR__  . '/ExpressionSearchSection/ExpressionSearchSection.js') ?>"
></script>
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. It already finished running (in a different computer) before JavaScript reaches your browser. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The server sends JS code to the client, so you can put some PHP in JS. Usually with <?php echo $myVar ?>, which "gives" to a JS variable the value of a PHP variable. I'm trying to do the same in an ES6 module.

Comment: What does "it" mean? Can you share more details, like code that triggers the problem?

Comment: You've added a code snippet where you read `$_SESSION` but never initialise sessions. Does that work? This is really a situation where you need to understand where each language runs and how they interact.

Comment: The session is initialized with `session_start()` in another file (and I can see on the webpage that I'm connected)

Comment: Alright, I'll trust you understand how server-side/client-side works. But you cannot diagnose JavaScript code if don't even know what the code is! What's the **output** of `let memberId = <?php echo (string)($_SESSION['memberId']); ?>;` and why does it throw a JavaScript parse error? How do you get the quotes in place?

Comment: On Chrome, I can see in the developer tools ("Sources" tab) that `let memberId = <?php echo (string)($_SESSION['memberId']); ?>;` has remained unchanged. There's at this line a red cross labeled `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: As you already know, the browser cannot execute PHP because it's a server-side language.

Comment: I expected the server to run the PHP and then return the result to the client, the JS code thus becoming `let memberId = <the member id returned by PHP>`, and this is what happens when the script type is not `module`. Our conversation doesn't progress much.